# How do I unlink a file-folder relationship?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

When asking IE to save an HTML page locally, with the option "Web page, complete", an html file is created along with a folder that contains all associated files (images, js, css etc).

An association is created between the html file and the folder, so that when the file is deleted/moved, so is the folder.

First, I'd like to know what this kind of association is called.

Further, I'd like to know how to "unlink" this file-folder association.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The association you are talking about is called "[Connected Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887(VS.85).aspx#connected)".

You can manage the 'connection' from Windows Explorer's `Tools | Folder Options` menu. In `View` tab there is `Managing pairs of Web pages and folders` option that you can set to your liking. Different options are

- Show and manage the pair as single file
- Show both parts and manage them individually
- Show both parts but manage as a single file

I think that at least IE still saves the folder when using "Web page, complete" as the save type, regardless of the setting.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more detail, the *connection* is just the folder having the same name as the .html file with "_files" appended. If you rename the folder (and ignore the warning) you will break the connection.

For example, if you wanted to delete the _files folder without deleting the .html file, rename the folder first and then delete it.